# css problem pushing image down

Tags: html, css, image

I have a text paragraph above an image.  When the paragraph grows and gains height, it pushes the image below down.  How can i make it so that if the paragraph grows in height, the image below still retains its original position?

Added code:

```
img.alertIcon {
    margin: 85px 0 0 15px;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: visible;
    clear: all;
}

#rightMain p {
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    float: left;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: if it's a background image just write background-position: top fixed;

Comment: overwrite or flow around, either works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I misunderstand what you're wanting, but maybe make your image have a fixed position. CSS position: fixed.

If you could post up an example that'd help as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one `position:fixed;` and if it is background`background-position: center bottom;`

Comment: But position fixed makes it so it ignores scroll

Comment: No not as a background image.

Comment: Use absolute instead of fixed.

Comment: @hurbid : try `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be to have the image float.

if the image is inside the paragraph simply add the `float: left` or `float:right` to the image so the image will stay in the same spot

Comment: No... it doesnt... because it changes vertical height based on the paragraph above.